# Adding scrolling to text C#

Tags: c#, text, scroll

So, I'm trying to make text vertically scroll in a form and I'm having trouble doing it. I would prefer to make it a label scrolling, but I highly doubt that's possible.
I don't have any code to reference because I haven't figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to scroll text box text vertically use try this it will work..

```
    textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
```